# python - pyinstaller _MEIPASS not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

**I need to use path of data inside script but I get this error:**

[image]

**this is the code:**

```
class GeneralData():

    def resource_path(relative_path):
        try:
            base_path = sys._MEIPASS
        except Exception:
            base_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

The error in this line `base_path = sys._MEIPASS` is : Cannot find reference '_MEIPASS' in 'sys.pyi | sys.pyi'

**And The error in Line Return is:** `Unexpected type(s): (Union[Union[str, bytes], Any], GeneralData) Possible types: (Union[bytes, PathLike[bytes]], Union[bytes, PathLike[bytes]]) (Union[str, PathLike[str]], Union[str, PathLike[str]]) (str, Union[bytes, str, PathLike]) (bytes, str) (bytes, bytes)`